# Scrapy - parsing all sub-pages of a given domain

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to parse kickstarter.com projects using scrapy, but can't figure out how to make the spider search projects that I don't explicitly specify under start_urls. I have the first part of the scrapy code figured out (I can extract the necessary information from one website), I just can't get it to do this for all projects under the domain kickstarter.com/projects.

From what I've read, I believe that parsing is possible (1) using links on the starting page (kickstarter.com/projects), (2) using links from one project page to jump to another project, and (3) using a site map (which I don't think kickstarter.com has) to locate webpages to parse.

I've spent hours trying each of these methods but and I am getting nowhere.

I've used the scrapy tutorial code and built on it.

Here is the part so far that works:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider   
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector  

from tutorial.items import kickstarteritem

class kickstarter(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'kickstarter'
    allowed_domains = ['kickstarter.com']    
    start_urls = ["http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/brucegoldwell/dragon-keepers-book-iv-fantasy-mystery-magic"]

    def parse(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        item = kickstarteritem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['name'] = x.select("//div[@class='NS-project_-running_board']/h2[@id='title']/a/text()").extract()
        item['launched'] = x.select("//li[@class='posted']/text()").extract()
        item['ended'] = x.select("//li[@class='ends']/text()").extract()
        item['backers'] = x.select("//span[@class='count']/data[@data-format='number']/@data-value").extract()
        item['pledge'] = x.select("//div[@class='num']/@data-pledged").extract()
        item['goal'] = x.select("//div[@class='num']/@data-goal").extract()
        return item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're subclassing `CrawlSpider`, *do not override `parse`*. `CrawlSpider`'s link crawling logic is contained within `parse`, which you really need.

As for the crawling itself, that's what the `rules` class attribute is for. I haven't tested it, but it should work:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from tutorial.items import kickstarteritem

class kickstarter(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'kickstarter'
    allowed_domains = ['kickstarter.com']    
    start_urls = ['http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recently-launched']

    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'\?page=\d+'),
            follow=True
        ),
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'/projects/'),
            callback='parse_item'
        )
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        xpath = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        loader = XPathItemLoader(item=kickstarteritem(), response=response)

        loader.add_value('url', response.url)
        loader.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="NS-project_-running_board"]/h2[@id="title"]/a/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('launched', '//li[@class="posted"]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('ended', '//li[@class="ends"]/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('backers', '//span[@class="count"]/data[@data-format="number"]/@data-value')
        loader.add_xpath('pledge', '//div[@class="num"]/@data-pledged')
        loader.add_xpath('goal', '//div[@class="num"]/@data-goal')

        yield loader.load_item()
```

The spider crawls the pages of the recently launched projects.

Also, use `yield` instead of `return`. It's better to keep your spider's output a generator and it lets you yield multiple items/requests without making a list to hold them.

Comment: I ran the code, and it works. This scrapes all the recently launched projects. If I want to scrape all projects (not just the recently launched ones), do I just alter the rules and start_urls? Thank you so much. This is a huge help. I don't know what I can do to repay you and the community. I'll pass on the act of kindness.

Comment: @user2167391: No problem. Scrapy is really awesome, but it's really hard to find examples online. As for Kickstarter, they make it hard to access *all* of their projects, so you'll have to see where they're all located.